# Projection matrix into subspace generated by two eigenvectors with purely imaginary eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M$ be a $4\times 4$ anti-symmetric matrix with real entries. Suppose $M$ has four eigenvectors $v_{1},v_{2},v_{3},v_{4}$. The first two eigenvectors $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$, while the eigenvectors $v_{3}$ and $v_{4}$ are associated to eigenvalues $-i\alpha$ and $i\alpha$, respectively, where $0 < \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. That is, the eigenvectors $v_{3}$ and $v_{4}$ are associated to purely imaginary eigenvalues, and the eigenvalue of $v_{3}$ is the complex conjugate of the eigenvalue of $v_{4}$.

**Question:** How can I construct a projection matrix $P$ into the subspace generated by $v_{3}$ and $v_{4}$? Is there a formula for such a matrix?

Comment: I don't understand the link between the question (in bold) and the long description of $M$ which seems completely useless for the question. If that is right, just delete all the useless part!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the matrix $P$ you're looking for has eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$ with associated eigenvalue $0$ and eigenvectors $v_3,v_4$ with associated eigenvalue $1$.

Using what you know about the eigenvalues of $M$, it is easy to see that $P = -M^2/\alpha^2$ is the matrix that you are after. If we want to express this purely in terms of $M$, we can write $P = 2M^2/ \operatorname{tr}(M^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean *orthogonal* projection, simple consider the orthogonal projection onto $(\ker M)^\perp$. The kernel of $M$ (that is, its nullity) is easy to compute. And its orthogonal is then also easy to compute.

Answer (score 1):

As $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ are the eigenvectors of an antisymmetric matrix, those are orhtogonal. Then the matrix of the orthogonal projection on $\operatorname{Span}\{v_3,v_4\}$ in the basis $\mathcal B = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is just

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$